# Как убрать отступы у input number (Mozilla)?

Tags: input, firefox

Делаю кроссбраузерность для сайта - [XTimer](http://xtimer.net/).
И все бы хорошо, если бы не Mozilla. Тут без слов, лучше сами посмотрите...

Проблема в `<input type="number">`, который пилит запредельные, не пойми откуда отступы на весь экран. Сначала думал, что затык в единицах измерения - vw/vh (которые использую). Но мозилла так же само добавляет отступы ко всем единицам: px, em, %, rem, pt...

Искал решение на хабре, тостере и в офишиал док. мозиллы. Ничего толкового не нашел. С меня печенька за помощь! ^^
[image: Сайт открыт в Firefox Mozilla (большие горизонтальные отступы)]

```css
form {
    font-size: 10vw;
}
form input {
    background-color: transparent;
}
form input[type="number"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Intro;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
}
form input[type="number"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
}
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table .numbers-of-time {
    line-height: 0;
}
table .name-of-time {
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: #ccc;
}
table .buttons-of-time {
    font-size: 0;
}
table .buttons-of-time input {
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr class="numbers-of-time">
                        <td><input type="number" id="for-hour" placeholder="00" min="0" max="23" /></td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="number" id="for-minute" placeholder="00" min="0" max="59" /></td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="number" id="for-second" placeholder="00" min="0" max="59" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="name-of-time">
                        <td>HOUR</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>MINUTE</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>SECOND</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="buttons-of-time" colspan="5">
                            <input type="button" id="play" onclick="Timer(); TimerPlay(); ShowPause();" />
                            <input type="button" id="pause" onclick="TimerPause(); ShowResume();" />
                            <input type="button" id="reset" onclick="DoReset();" />
                            <input type="button" id="refresh" onclick="XbuttonNorm();" />
                            <audio id="soundOfEnd" loop>
                                <source src="sound/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </audio>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input[type="number"] {
  width: 6em;
}
```

Comment: Теперь такие "ужасные" отступы еще и на Хроме))
Но в Мозиле они немного уменьшильсь!
Наилучше подходит 2em и даже скорее всего "идеально", но вопрос все же остаеться: "Почему Mozilla делает отступы у input number?!"

Comment: Это не отступы, а ширина. Если хочешь какое-то конкретное значение, его стоит задавать явно, а не рассчитывать, что оно у всех одинаковое по умолчанию.